# AttributeError 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have A pandas dataframe, and I want to change the content of a column, depending on its current value. If the record has the value 'INFINITY', assign a constant, elsewhere, assign its current value casted to number. This is my code so far:

`data_frame['my_column'] = np.where(data_frame['my_column'] == 'INFINITY', 999999999999, data_frame['my_column'].to_numeric())`

The problem is that this code raises this exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\HUGO~1.VIL\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_28924/1872682007.py in <module>
----> 1 data_frama['my_column'] = np.where(data_frame['my_column'] == 'INFINITY', 999999999999, data_frame['my_column'].to_numeric())

~\Documents\code\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'
```

How can I instruct NumPy `where` to take the current value and cast it to number?

Comment: You aren't telling `where` to do anything.  `where` takes 3 arguments, which are evaluated in full before being passed it. It's the pandas object `data_frame['my_column']` that's having problems with the `to_numeric`. Pandas docs that is recommending `where` is doing a poor job of explaining it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your issue had nothing to do with `where`. `to_numeric` is not a valid Series method. However, the top level [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) method exists.

Thus, you should replace `data_frame['my_column'].to_numeric()` with:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_numeric(data_frame['my_column'])
```

In your context:

```
data_frame['my_column'] = np.where(data_frame['my_column'] == 'INFINITY', 999999999999, pd.to_numeric(data_frame['my_column']))
```